# BlueNRG-MS not generating any advertising reports in observer mode

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, stm32, bluenrg

I am currently working with two *STM32F401RE* Nucleo boards with *IDB05A1* Bluetooth LE extensions using the BlueNRG-MS stack. One board is configured in advertiser mode. The other boards is configured in **observer** mode and is supposed to print all messages received from the advertiser.

When I start the observation procedure with the vendor specific command as seen below, all works fine and I can process `LE_ADVERTISING_EVENT` in the `HCI_EVENT_CB` function.

```
aci_gap_start_observation_procedure(0x4000, 0x4000, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
```

When I try to do the same thing with the standardised Bluetooth commands as shown below, no `LE_ADVERTISING_REPORT` is generated and processable in `HCI_EVENT_CB`, even though the Bluetooth standard say it should.

```
hci_le_set_scan_parameters(0x00, 0x4000, 0x4000, 0x00, 0x00);
hci_le_set_scan_enable(0x01, 0x00);
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enable `LL_WITOHUT_HOST` mode by
calling `ACI_HAL_WRITE_CONFIG_DATA` with parameters:

- Offset = 0x2C
- Length = 1
- Value = 1

However, it is recommended to stick with GAP and GATT (not to enable this mode)
because the host guarantees the full compatibility with the BLE specification.